# Tag Merge of visual-studio-2013 and vs-2013

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

It appears the tag [vs-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-2013) could be labeled as a synonym of [visual-studio-2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013).

Comment: The same goes for vs-2014ctp and visual-studio-2014-ctp.

Comment: @Artjom - Nice find. I check VS2008 and VS2010, but did not find a duplicate there.

Comment: No more questions with the tag vs-2013. I edited the last one. Can we just wait for it to burn itself?

Comment: @gunr2171 Why would you bump up all those questions by editing when we have a perfectly good system for solving this problem? That tag will just get re-created again, VS is a common abbreviation for Visual Studio. A synonym is most appropriate.

Comment: And while we're at it, let's approve [the other proposed synonyms for this tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio-2013/synonyms).

Comment: @CodyGray, I edited only one question. When I went to the vs-2013 tag, there was only one item.

Comment: It gets recreated about once a month, it's on my deaded list.  A synonym would be nice.  I just wish that the synonym system wasn't so broken that the only way to get synonyms for low-traffic tags was to ask for diamond mod intervention via Meta...